# How to handle lambda expression with 3 parameters in Java8

Tags: java, android, lambda

Hello I have the following code :

```
 view.setOnLongClickListener((viewL) -> {
        final CharSequence[] optionsDialog = {"Edit", "Delete"};
        ((MainActivity) context).myDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(optionsDialog, 0,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        if(i==0){
                            final Intent myIntent = new Intent (context, MainInputActivity.class);
                            myIntent.putExtra("request", 8);
                            myIntent.putExtra("oldTask", mySubTask.getSubTaskText());
                            myIntent.putExtra("taskCode", mySubTask.getSubtaskCode());
                            ((MainActivity) context).startActivityForResult(myIntent, 8);
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                        if(i==1){
                            realm.executeTransaction((realm) -> mySubTask.deleteSubtask());
                            realm.refresh();
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            ((MainActivity) context).updateWidgets();
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

So here I have one SAM expression, and inside I want to write the `((MainActivity) context).myDialog.setSingleChoiceItems` as lambda too. The problem is that `setSingleChoiceItems` have 3 parameters and I don't know how am I supposed to convert the snippet into lambda. Is it even possible ? According to my IDE it is, thats why I ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` is a functional interface (i.e. has only one abstract method) :

```
view.setOnLongClickListener((viewL) -> {
    final CharSequence[] optionsDialog = {"Edit", "Delete"};
    ((MainActivity) context).myDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(optionsDialog, 0,
            (DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) -> {
                if(i==0){
                    final Intent myIntent = new Intent (context, MainInputActivity.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("request", 8);
                    myIntent.putExtra("oldTask", mySubTask.getSubTaskText());
                    myIntent.putExtra("taskCode", mySubTask.getSubtaskCode());
                    ((MainActivity) context).startActivityForResult(myIntent, 8);
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
                if(i==1){
                    realm.executeTransaction((realm) -> mySubTask.deleteSubtask());
                    realm.refresh();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    ((MainActivity) context).updateWidgets();
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }     
            });
        });
```

Note that only the last argument of `setSingleChoiceItems` is converted to a lambda expression.